# how convert web browser control into web application, and some events

Tags: asp.net, windows

You people might be think this question is pretty simple but really I am structed here. Could you please give me a proper solution for this

I have a Windows sample like the following in button click event

```
AuthURI= "http://.......";   

**Webbrowser1.Navigate(AuthURI);**



private void **Webbrowser1_DocumentCompleted**(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs **e**)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Url.ToString().Contains("code="))
                {
                    string[] responseOauth = Regex.Split(e.Url.ToString(), "&");
                    for (int i = 0; i < responseOauth.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        string[] nvPair = Regex.Split(responseOauth[i], "=");
                        drive.AccessCode = nvPair[1];


                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

**This is windows application code but now I want to change this application into web application**

but I strucked **WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e**  how to pass this event like e.Url in my web application

what is replacement for this event I tried in google but exact result I didn't get. Please give me a proper solution for this

Comment: It'd be best to avoid using `WebBrowser` as part of an ASP.NET application. If you can accomplish your goal with [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that would be better. It is possible to use `WebBrowser`, but it's really meant for use in a Win Forms app and so you have to go through some extra trouble. It's overkill for ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks for your reply mr.mason , yes I am trying to avoid this WebBrowser control but in ASP.net webform I am not getting the events same like WebBrowser control which I mention in code.